# next.js shallow routing not working expectantly while adding a query string

Tags: next.js, next-router

#### The problem:

when attempting shallow routing with changing (adding or removing NOT updating) the query string in Next.js the page is reloaded and the shallow ignored.

**How can I prevent reloading while changing the query string?**

---

#### Example:

from: `example.com/page1/?a=2`

to: `example.com/page1/?a=2&b=3`

---

#### Code:

```js
const newSearch = '?a=2&b=3'
router.push(`/page1/${newSearch}`, null, { shallow: true })
```

I also try:

```js
const newSearch = '?a=2&b=3'
router.push(`/page1/${newSearch}`, `/page1/${newSearch}`, { shallow: true })
```

Comment: Passing [`shallow: true`](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing) in the `router.push` call simply prevents data fetching methods (`getStaticProps`, `getServerSideProps`) from rerunning. It does not prevent the page from re-rendering (that can't be prevented, as the route changes and that always triggers a re-render) - the page should not fully reload however.

Answer (score 0):

router.push(`/page1?${finalQuery.join("&")}`, undefined, {
shallow: true,
});

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

I just disable the `shallow` since this is an [Autmatic static optimization](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/automatic-static-optimization) I realized that it avoids query string updates. It works for me only disabling shallow. Anyway, I see the `getServerSideProps` ever runs with/without `shallow`.